# <li> is not displaying in ie 8 without wrapping <ul>

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

```
<p>
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>

    <li>
        this is a test &quot;li&quot; without a parent &quot;ul&quot;</li>
    <li>
        this is a test &quot;li&quot; without a parent &quot;ul&quot;</li>
    <li>
        this is a test &quot;li&quot; without a parent &quot;ul&quot;</li>
    <li>
        this is a test &quot;li&quot; without a parent &quot;ul&quot;</li>
```

Above list items will not be displayed in IE8 when not wrapped into an `<ul>` tag. Is it a bug or the expected behavior ?

Comment: because it's not valid to have li without ul so don't expect it to work in any browser

Comment: its working on other pages only one page is not.

Comment: @user10559419 you may see many browsers make their best attempt to interpret ambiguous or invalid markup since that's a better experience than the page crashing. However it doesn't mean it's supported syntax or should be expected to work.

Answer (score 1):

The [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) requires `<li>` elements to be a child of specific parent elements. It looks like a parent element to `<li>` is missing from your example.

Not the spec but [Mozilla’s documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li):

> The HTML `<li>` element is used to represent an item in a list. **It must
>   be contained in a parent element: an ordered list (`<ol>`), an unordered
>   list (`<ul>`), or a menu (`<menu>`).**

Answer (score 0):

`li` stands for "List Element". Therefore, you should enclose them in a `ul` (unordered list) or `ol` (ordered list).
`li` tag alone may likely work in modern browsers (but HTML code will not conform to the standard you are using), but not in Internet Explorer 8!

Comment: There should be a way ? only few client is using old ie but we need to use without ul or other parent tag

Comment: @user10559419 I would challenge why you don’t need a parent tag. Is it for styling? If so, that might be a new question asking how to simulate a list without using using ul/li elements. Granted you’ll probably have a few people wondering why you can’t simply use the elements made for that job. :)

Answer (score 0):

First this is not the correct syntax to use **Li** without **ol** or **UL**.

If then also you want to display the list in IE 8 without adding **ul** or **ol** then try to create a JS function that identifies the IE 8.

Then if it is IE 8 then loop though all the **li** elements.

Then add '•' character before the text.

It will look similar like bullets with **li** elements.

• one

• two

• three